# How to get the Index of the item from list box which is pressed (list contain button which is bind with command not with click)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having List Box which contain the buttons. We can add any no of buttons. I have added the buttons into the list called "AddedButtonList" through c# and bind that list as follow:

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:AddedAction}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Title}"
                        Height="40"
                        Width="100"
                        Command="{Binding Command}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding actionsRecordVmObj.AddedActionsList}" Width="Auto">
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

we can add any no of buttons by using above code in xaml because i have bind all the properties from code behind.
the code behind is:

```
 public abstract class AddedAction
    {
        public bool IsDisable { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string ButtonIndex { get; set; }
        public abstract ICommand Command { get; }
    }



 public class AddedSourceFileActionVm : AddedAction
    {
        public ICommand _command;
        //constructor
        public AddedSourceFileActionVm()
        {
            Title = "Source File";
            _command = new RelayCommand(p => AddedSourceFileActionCommandExecuted(null), p => CanAddedSourceFileActionCommandExecute());
        }
```

All buttons are bind with command
(buttons may be repeat in the list). 
I want to get the index of the button(Item from list) which get pressed.
I read many answers some of were saying use AlternationCount but when I want the index in code behind I am not able to do that because I use Command for binding and they showed for click event.
I cant use

```
    private void lstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
                Button button = sender as Button;           
                int index = _myListBoxName.Items.IndexOf(button.DataContext); 
      }
```

because I am using MVVM and I bind all buttons with command.
so please suggest some solution for this.

or in short how to get the index of button which is pressed from list?
Thanks in advance....

Comment: You can pass the current DataContext to the Button's CommandParameter by `CommandParameter="{Binding}"`. It will be passed to the `object` parameter of the Command's Execute method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can easily get the index:
1. Define an `abstract` `event` on your `AddedAction`.
2. Subscribe to the `event` when creating an `AddedAction` instance
3. Raise the `event` when `AddedAction.Command` is executed
4. Get the index on the event handler

For example:

```
public abstract class AddedAction
{
    //define the event
    public abstract event EventHandler CommandExecuted;

    public abstract ICommand Command { get; }
    //...
}
public class AddedSourceFileActionVm : AddedAction
{
    public override event EventHandler CommandExecuted;

    private void AddedSourceFileActionCommandExecuted(object obj)
    {
        //invoke the event
        CommandExecuted?.Invoke(this, null);
        //...
    }
    //...
}
public class ActionsRecordVm
{
    public List<AddedAction> AddedActionsList { get; } = new List<AddedAction>();
    public void AddNewAddedAction()
    {
        var addedAction = new AddedSourceFileActionVm();
        //Subscribe to the event
        addedAction.CommandExecuted += AddedAction_CommandExecuted;
        AddedActionsList.Add(addedAction);
    }

    private void AddedAction_CommandExecuted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the index
        int index = AddedActionsList.IndexOf((AddedAction)sender);

        //...
    }
    //...
}
```